# Retrieve multiple values from matlab string

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, char

I currently have a large single row array of chars... I also have two arrays, the first array has all the start indexes of data I would like to retrieve from the char array, the second array has all the end indexes for the data. How can I retrieve all these wanted values from my char array without using a loop?

So far I have tried doing

```
     chararray(1,start(:):end(:))
```

but this will only retrieve the first value I would like!

Cheers!

Comment: Don't you need a loop - `for iter = 1:numel(start), chararray(1,start(iter):end(iter))`, where `iter` would be the loop iterator?

Comment: @Divakar Hi I was hoping there would be a simpler way as this loop would be extremely large!

Comment: Are the intervals same for all entries of `start` and `end`? Intervals as in `start(1):end(1)`, `start(2):end(2)` and so on.

Comment: @Divakar They all are yes! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
chararray(bsxfun(@plus,start1(:)-start1(1),start1(1):end1(1)))
```

This would create a 2D char array where each row be the output from each iteration of your loop code.

Also, please note that I am using `start1` and `end1` to represent your `start` and `end` arrays respectively, so as not to create a clash with the reserved terminate scope `end` used by MATLAB.